# How to convert "Wed Apr 10 03:48:00 PDT 2019" to 2019-04-10 03:48:00 in scala?

Tags: scala

I have value like following `"Wed Apr 10 03:48:00 PDT 2019"` and want to convert or parse in `2019-04-10 03:48:00`.

My excepted result is:

```
2019-04-10 03:53:02
```

Comment: give me result in scala without using Spark Framework.

Comment: This or similar has been asked and answered countless times. Please use your search engine before asking the same question again.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
val dateString = "Wed Apr 10 03:48:00 PDT 2019"

val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)

val parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString , dtf)

val formatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").format(parsed)
```

Remember to pass explicitly `Locale` as the second argument to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` because this code might fail on parsing **Apr** part on a computer with different default locale!